# Invalidate Timer when application enters background

Tags: ios

I have code to invalidate the timer when the app enters the background but when i pressed the home button waited and opened the app back up, the timer continued the whole time without stopping.

My Timer code :

```
-(void) updateTimer {

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
second = (NSUInteger)round(timeInterval);
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u:%02u",
                    second / 3600, (second / 60) % 60, second % 60];
hhmmssLabel.text = string;
pauseTimeInterval = timeInterval;


}
-(void)pauseTimer {

[tickerTimer invalidate];
tickerTimer = nil;
}

-(void) unPauseTimer {

startDate = [NSDate date] ;
startDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((-1)*(pauseTimeInterval))];
tickerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}
```

and my code to see if the application left the foreground

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
if([tickerTimer isValid] && scoringBegan == YES){
[self pauseTimer];
scoringBegan = NO;
[phonePos invalidate];
[baseReset invalidate];
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

    {

    if([tickerTimer isValid] && scoringBegan == YES){
        [self pauseTimer];
        scoringBegan = NO;
        [phonePos invalidate];
        [baseReset invalidate];


       }
    }
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{

    if([tickerTimer isValid] && scoringBegan == YES){
        [self pauseTimer];
        scoringBegan = NO;
        [phonePos invalidate];
        [baseReset invalidate];
    }
}
```

*****UPDATE**************
the timer resumes when the user is going a certain speed, and correct me if i am wrong but location services still work in the background. So the timer automatically resumes after paused. So is there a way to pause location services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Location updates only work in the background if you have put the flag `"App Registers for Location Updates"` inside of your plist. Remove that flag and you won't be able to update in the background. As for your timer, I'd just log a bool that it went into the background. Then when you get the `applicationWillEnterForeground` notification, if the bool is correct you can just invalidate the timer there (since it won't continue to increment in the background).

Alternatively, you could call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` and clean up your timers and pause a couple other things for a few more seconds.

And yes, you can pause location updates by calling `stopUpdatingLocation` or `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`..or whatever is applicable to your location update type

Comment: i used [CLController.locMgr stopUpdatingLocation];    Now i just have to test it Thanks

Comment: I tested it this morning and it works perfectly :) thanks again